# How to get rid of the warning while rendering MathJax in IE

Tags: javascript, html, mathjax

Although I found a similar Question 
[Using mark of the web with MathML](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9894906/using-mark-of-the-web-with-mathml),
I couldn't find the solution.
I tried the following sample from MathJax website

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>MathJax TeX Test Page</title>
<script type="text/x-mathjax-config">
  MathJax.Hub.Config({tex2jax: {inlineMath: [['$','$'], ['\\(','\\)']]}});
</script>
<script type="text/javascript"
  src="http://cdn.mathjax.org/mathjax/latest/MathJax.js?config=TeX-AMS-MML_HTMLorMML">
</script>
</head>
<body>
<span style='font-size:130%'>
When $a \ne 0$, there are two solutions to \(ax^2 + bx + c = 0\) and they are
$$x = {-b \pm \sqrt{b^2-4ac} \over 2a}.$$
</span>
</body>
</html>
```

I get

> Internet Explorer restricted this webpage from running scripts or
>   ActiveX controls.

warning in IE 9.

This mathematical blog

http://swanlotus.com/varieties-of-multiplication/

works fine in IE 9.

Just wondering what changes do I need to make to the sample to fix this issue.

Comment: Note from the future: cdn.mathjax.org is nearing its end-of-life, check https://www.mathjax.org/cdn-shutting-down for migration tips (and perhaps update your post for future readers).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problems like these exist because you're running the webpage directly from your computer, in other words you'll need to serve the page using a http server ( like apache, IIS, etc ).

You can still disable the warning, if you want to, by going to Tools (menu) → Internet Options → Security (tab) → Custom Level (button) → and Disable Automatic prompting for ActiveX controls. This will only apply to your computer obviously.

Anyway, if you're developing a webpage of sorts i recommend you run it in a http server in your localhost ( try installing [WAMP](http://www.wampserver.com/en/) for instance, gives you apache and php + mysql, and its easy to use )

Comment: Awesome!!! Served the page using IIS - it worked without displaying any warnings.